# How to make the maven release plugin work on widows with SSH outside of git-bash?

Tags: git, maven, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a mvn release command that works on Windows inside a git-bash but as soon as I try in a cmd window, it fails.

The command is :

```
mvn -X -B -Dusername=git release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

The error is the following :

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

My maven settings file is located as the default path `~/.m2/settings.xml` and looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>github.com</id>
        <username>git</username>
        <privateKey>C:\Users\nicol\.ssh\id_ed25519</privateKey>
        <!-- also tried with ${user.home}/.ssh/id_ed25519 -->
        <passphrase>nico</passphrase>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

I generated a private key using the command from the Github guide on deploy keys :

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "git@github.com"
```

I uploaded the public key on the "Deploy keys" section of the Github repo.

Here's how the pom.xml looks like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.myusername</groupId>
    <artifactId>myrepo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.scm.id>github.com</project.scm.id>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/myusername/myrepo</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below the version details :

- git version 2.34.1.windows.1
- java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
- Apache Maven 3.8.4

I tested with and without ssh agent on git-bash : it worked.

With cmd, I keep getting the same error.

What's going on ? How will I make it work on cmd ?

A bit of context: What I'm trying to build fails on ubuntu linux due to some tricky library issue and as it builds a Windows executable, it would probably make more sense to build on Windows. I plan to put the whole process into a Github workflow so I'd like it to validate it locally first. If the Github workflow/actions has an embedded Git-Bash, that could help too.

*** EDIT after @khmarbaise's comment ***

As I saw a mess in known_hosts file, here's what I did:

- deleted entries of known_hosts file
- generated public/private keys with command above
- uploaded public key in the "Deploy keys" section of the repo

Then, in a cmd prompt, the following scenario worked fine for me:

- git clone ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
- cd myrepo
- echo. >> README.md
- git add README.md
- git commit -a -m "added space at the end of the README"
- git push

Then I tried again the maven release command:

```
mvn -X -B -Dusername=git release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

And had the error again:

```
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: Do you have a config file in your `.ssh/` directory?

Comment: I have a ~/.ssh/known_hosts file which contains keys that don't look like the one I'm using so that's a bit confusing

Comment: The known_host would result in a yes/no question to accept it permanently. Have you tried to clone on plain windows with git and changed something and pushed something your git repository on plain command line... because it looks like the permissions on the repo are not the way you expect or the wrong key is being used...

Comment: I restarted with an empty ~/.ssh/known_hosts, re-generated public/private key, uploaded public key to the Github repo, git cloned in SSH mode, and git pushed something successfully into the repo in cmd. Then I launched the mvn release command and it failed again.

Comment: sorry my settings.xml file need update

Comment: still not working even with the right passphrase in the settings.xml

Comment: The same message: `Permission denied`?

Comment: Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: Based on the `-X` in your call...do you have the logging output because at the beginning it's writing out which `settings.xml` is exactly read... check if this is the correct one?

Comment: apart from I have asked if you have a `.ssh/config` file to associate your keys with a particular host? Can you say something about that? And also how it is configured?

Comment: I don't have this file .ssh/config. From the logs, the global settings is C:\Users\nicol\Downloads\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin\apache-maven-3.8.4\conf\settings.xml (unmodified from original distribution) and the user settings C:\Users\nicol\.m2\settings.xml is actually the one I posted.

Comment: I think I understood that git-bash ships with an embedded utility that prompts for a passphrase (by opening a dialog box) so I retried on cmd with a key without a passphrase and it worked.